# Android show image from camera horizontal scroll view listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to show image from camera in HorizontalScrollView Images.

Currently, In each item of List View HorizontalScrollView is added and each 
HorizontalScrollView displayes the images dynamically on the basis of data fetched from the sqlite. Sqlite is preloaded with the data that is downloaded from our application server.

Also, In each list item 'Camera' button is added. On click event of this button .I am adding images captured from Camera to the existing HorizontalScrollView.

I am adding some code snippet from my application -

1) First I'm trying to show images dynamically in HorizontalScrollView from sqlite in ArrayAdapter -

```
@Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View row = convertView;
                final Holder holder;
                if (row == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater vi;
                    vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                    row = vi.inflate(R.layout.all_post_row, null);
                    holder = new Holder();
                    holder.horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)row.findViewById(R.id.hlist);
                    holder.lLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.innerlay);


                    row.setTag(holder);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder = (Holder) row.getTag();

                }

                final All_Post all_Post = data.get(position);
                String strListItem_ActivityId = all_Post.getStrActivityId();
                Log.e("strListItem_ActivityId ", " = " + strListItem_ActivityId);
                dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(AllPosts_Page.this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ActivityObjectList where activityId " + "= ? ", new String[]{strListItem_ActivityId});
                imageArray.clear();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imageaudioPath"));
                        Log.e("imagePath ", " = " + imagePath);
                        imageArray.add(imagePath);
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();

                 holder.lLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
                final Iterator<String> it = imageArray.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext())
                {
                    final String imgElement = it.next();
                    int imgArraySize = imageArray.size();
                    Log.e("imgArraySize "," = " + imgArraySize);

                    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView (getContext());
                    final ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar(getContext(),null ,android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall);

                    imageView.setTag(it);
                    pBar.setTag(it);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_placeholder);
                    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder).resize(newWidth,fixHeight).into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess() {
                                        if (pBar != null) {
                                            pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError() {

                                    }
                                });

                                holder.lLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
                                holder.lLinearLayout.addView(pBar);
    }
```

2) 2) Here is my Camera button click event in ArrayAdapter class -

```
 holder.imgBtn_Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Camera" + " = ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                }
            });
```

3) Here is onActivityResult method implementation  which is in Activity class -

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
        {
            activityObj_Id++;
            intoString = Integer.toString(activityObj_Id);

            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
            String dateformat = s.format(new Date());
            Log.e("format", " and activityObj_Id = " + dateformat + " & " +   activityObj_Id);

            imageCamera_Path = activityObj_Id +"_"+ dateformat+".png";
            downloadstatus = "1";
            Log.e("imageCamera_Path", "= " + imageCamera_Path);

            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            }
        Log.e("Data Save","in onActivityResult Succesfully !!!!");
    }
```

The above code should show the images captured from camera into HorizontalScrollView. However, images are not getting added to scroll view. I am not able to understand where does it went wrong ? I have tried to modify code in many ways. However it did not help.

Please take look at my code snippets and let me know if anything is missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Please can someone help ?